# htmlworker.parsetolist c# Unable to create SSL / TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

this is my code

the problem in  var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stred, null);

the error msg Unable to create SSL / TLS secure channel

in the past the code work code but in the last week dont work

```
         Document document;
        if (!rotate)
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
        else
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 50, 50, 25, 25);
        try
        {
            var output = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

            document.Open();
            

            StringReader stred = new StringReader(contents);

            var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stred, null);

            foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
            {
                document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
            }
```

Comment: Well, that code is forcing SSL3 or TLS1.0, both being extremely outdated, deprecated and considered insecure. Perhaps the client OS changed, perhaps the server changed. We can't help you, you need to find out what's going on with the site/server you're using

Comment: i try with anorther code without ssl3 or tls but the same prb that mean something going wrong in the serveur ?

Comment: Somebody must of install a Security update that Microsoft released in June that disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers.  The solution is on clients to add before the request is generated the following : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;